# Android string compare is false

Tags: android, string, compare

I have the following piece of code:

```
String week = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("weekNumber");
String correctWeek = Integer.toString(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

if (week == correctWeek) {
    correct();
}

else incorrect();
```

They are both "3", but the comparation result is false and I don't know why:

[image]

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `equals()` to compare strings for content, not `==`.

`==` will check if the *objects* are the same.

```
String foo = "foo";

if (foo == foo) {
    // same object, so true
}
```

```
String foo1 = "foo";
String foo2 = "foo";

if (foo1 == foo2) {
    // both are string literals set at compile time, so true
}
```

```
String foo1 = loadFoo1(); // imagine this returns "foo"
String foo2 = loadFoo2(); // imagine this also returns "foo"

if (foo1 == foo2) {
    // not the same object, and not string literals, so false
}

if (foo1.equals(foo2)) {
    // both strings hold "foo", so true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two strings are separate objects, and "==" tests if its two operands are the same exact object.

To compare strings, try week.equals(correctWeek)

Answer (score 0):

The "==" operator is used for reference comparison. It checks if both objects point to the same memory location, which returns *false* in your case as you are comparing two different string objects.

For your purpose you should use .equals(), which evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.

Example:

```
String week =  new String("3"); 
String correctWeek =  new String("3"); 
System.out.println(week == correctWeek); 
System.out.println(week.equals(correctWeek));
```

will output:

```
false
true
```